TypeScript warning: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ [key: number]: CalendarEvent; }'
I am working on a NextJs project with TypeScript.
When I try to use .map on an array of objects I get a TypeScript warning:
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ [key: number]: CalendarEvent; }'
My type definition in definitions.ts file is like:
export type CalendarEvent = {
start: number;
duration: number;
};

export type EventsData = {
[key: number]: CalendarEvent;
}[];

Then in my component:
export default function CalendarWeek(){
const events: EventsData = [
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }, { start: 700, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }, { start: 700, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 120, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }],
[{ start: 600, duration: 45 }],
];
return (
<>
  events[0].map((event: CalendarEvent) => (
     // events[0] is an array of objects. events[0].map shows the above mentioned warning.
     <div key={event.start}>
       {event.start}
     </div>
  ))}
</>
)}

Am I doing something wrong in the type definition?
I tried adding the type event: CalenarEvent in map function
events[0].map((event: CalendarEvent) => ....

But that didn't make a diference.

Update: changing the definition of EventData to export type EventsData = CalendarEvent[][]; Solved the issue.
